# How to specify a range using argparse?

Tags: python, range, argparse

My parser states the following:

```
parser.add_argument(
    '--degree',
    type=int,
    default=3,
    nargs="*",
    help="Degree of the 'poly' kernel. (default=3)."
)
```

I would like to specify a range instead of just using nargs.

For example: 0 8 2 (start, stop, step) should specify that I want the values 0 2 4 6 8.

Should I just use np.arange as datatype or maybe just specifying 3 args and creating the array myself. Please LMK if there is a better way.

Comment: `type` is a function that takes one string, and returns something (or raises an error).  With '*' the user can provide 0,1,... numbers  Use your own code, after parsing to convert those to a range.  Often it's easier to process the values after parsing than to do something fancy in `argparse`.

Comment: `args.degree` will be a list of ints. Do what you want with those.  Or complain if the user provided the wrong number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `nargs=3` to require 3 values for the parameter.

```
parser.add_argument(
    '--degree',
    type=int,
    default=3,
    nargs=3,
)

args = parser.parse_args(['--degree', '1', '2', '3'])
numpy_arr = np.arange(*args.degree)
```

Alternatively, you can pass comma-separated values and use `type` to convert the value to a range:

```
def get_np_arange(value):
   try:
       values = [int(i) for i in value.split(',')]
       assert len(values) in (1, 3)
   except (ValueError, AssertionError):
       raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
           'Provide a CSV list of 1 or 3 integers'
       )

   # return our value as is if there is only one
   if len(values) == 1:
       return np.array(values)

   # if there are three - return a range
   return np.arange(*values)


parser.add_argument(
    '--degree',
    type=get_np_arange,
)

args = parser.parse_args()
numpy_arr = args.degree
print(numpy_arr)
```

Example output:

```sh
➜  ~ python test.py --degree 1,2    
usage: prog [-h] --degree DEGREE
prog: error: argument --degree: Provide a CSV list of 1 or 3 integers
➜  ~ python test.py --degree a,2,3
usage: prog [-h] --degree DEGREE
prog: error: argument --degree: Provide a CSV list of 1 or 3 integers
➜  ~ python test.py --degree 20
[20]
➜  ~ python test.py --degree 1,10,4
[1 5 9]
```

Comment: Thanks @Vlad Emelianov! What if the user only specifies one value? How would I handle this? an int wouldn't be iterable. I would still like to return a list though. So for example returning [2] (if the degree specified is 2).

Comment: `get_np_arange` get a value as a string: `1,2,3`. 
First, we split values by a comma and convert them to integers: values = [1, 2, 3]
If any of these values cannot be parsed as an integer, `ValueError` is raised, so we handleit in `except ValueError` and show a helpful message to a user. Any `argparse.ArgumentTypeError` raised during argument parsing will be shown to a user as an argument parsing error.

Then we `assert` that there are exactly three values after separation: `len(values) == 3` . If it is not 3, then we handle `AssertionError` to show the same message to the user.

Comment: The function returns a numpy array, and it is stored in `args.degree`.  So we can start working with it.

Comment: Hmm but I don't want to have an array of specified values. I want the user to specify start, stop and step. For example: 1,6,2 should be transformed into  [1,3,5]. And 2 should be transformed to [2].

Comment: I have just updated my answer with output examples. Try it with `--degree 1,6,2`, it prints `[1 5 9]`. Please notice that at the very end of `get_np_arange` function, I pass all values to `np.arange`, so we get a numpy range.

Comment: Gotcha, but this forces us to put always 3 inputs right? So for just having one degree I would have to write 2, 2, 0? Is there a way to overcome that?

Comment: Well, if you want `np.arange` to work with any number of arguments, just modify assertion: `assert len(values) <= 3`. So, your degree argument can accept one, two or three values. Do not forget to update a message for user to `Provide a CSV list of up to three integers`

Comment: Sorry, finally understood what you are trying to achieve. Updated my code